# running multiple MATLAB scripts in a row

Tags: matlab

This is a very simple question:
I have several MATLAB scripts that I want to run, each of which takes several hours. How can I make them all run in a row (so that script 2 starts after script 1 ends, script 3 starts after script 2 ends, etc.)?

Sorry if this was been answered! I was unable to find the relevant posts on this board.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one master script:

```
script1;
script2;
script3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the script name into one file,

```
run script1.m;
run script2.m;
```

and run the file